# The Define of new

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, detect

Today,I find a source code about memory leak detect,and in his header file,I find the following macro definition,can somebody tell me what this means?thank you !

```
#ifndef MC_NO_REDEFINITION
    #define new MC_NEW
    #define MC_NEW new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
        #define mc_new new
else
//use defined function name instead of keyword new & delete
    #define debug_new new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
#endif
```

doses this means,new represents `new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)`,if this is true,how the compiler know what I really want to call when I use new in my code?

Comment: #ifndef MEMCHECK 
#define MEMCHECK
void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file,const char* func,const int line);
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* file,const char* func,const int line);
#endif 

#ifndef NEW_H
 #define new new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
#endif

Answer (score 5):

The same code that provides those macros must also provide suitable definitions of a global `operator new()` which takes the appropriate additional arguments, such as:

```
void * operator new(std::size_t n, char const * file, char const * func, char const * line)
{
    // log file, func, line

    return operator new(n);
}
```

There should also be a matching `operator delete()`.

Note that `new` is a keyword, and I think that replacing the keyword with a macro is actually not condoned by the standard.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.there is no problem when I only use MC_NEW to replace new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__),but the problem comes when I use "new" keyword to replace it,is seems ambiguity,and it reminds me that it can't find the appropriate new function.so I really want to know is the effect of these three macro definitions.

Comment: I have three file，the following is the first file：

#ifndef MEMCHECK 
#define MEMCHECK
void* operator new(size_t size, const char* file,const char* func,const int line);
void* operator new[](size_t size, const char* file,const char* func,const int line);
#endif 

#ifndef NEW_H
 #define new new(__FILE__,__FUNCTION__,__LINE__)
#endif

Answer (score 2):

> Note that new is a keyword, and I think that replacing the keyword
>   with a macro is actually not condoned by the standard.

Absolutely right. It results in undefined behavior. This is a Microsoft hack that should not be imitated.